# Initialize a derived constructor from base clase or not

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor

What is the difference between:

```
Biceps::Biceps():Body(height, kg)
{
    this->height = height;
    this->kg = kg;
}
```

and

```
Biceps::Biceps():Body(height, kg)
{

}
```

I already initialized the variables in my base class, so why should or shouldn't initialize in my derived class?

Comment: What and where are the different variables named `height` and `kg` ?

Comment: No where, their name is the same everywhere. I should name them differently?

Comment: You should provide a compilable snippet, with proper declarations. `this->height = height;` suggest that you have two variables named `height`, otherwise you're just self-assigning. But there's no point in guessing until we have the full picture.

Comment: The difference is that the second one assigns values to `this->height` and `this->kg`. There's nothing here to tell readers what those variables are or where they are defined or what the base class constructor does with its arguments.